# Browser game programming in linux

Tags: linux, flash, browser

My friend and I are looking to play around with building a browser game (e.g. Farmville) from a linux environment. Flash seems to be the way most browser games are built, but from what I google flash programming can't be easily (at all?) done from linux. Java seems like the leading candidate, but I am rather bamboozled by all the options out there. What platforms should I consider?

As an aside, I have a strong-ish C++ background and some professional experience with Python.

Comment: There's some open/free tools that can generate SWF files, but generating the file is the SMALLEST part of Flash development. You really do want the full Flash devel package from Adobe, which gives you debuggers, inspectors, nice editors, etc...

Comment: @MarcB, Thanks for the advice -- sounds like I should program in Windows (ugg) instead to take advantage of the Adobe software. I guess it's time to fire up cygwin again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For browser based games, there are 2 main options if I remember correctly:
Flash, as you've already noted is the most common options. Usually this is done using adobe's software (around $200) or just an actionscript compiler (which is more programming like then normal flash). For Linux, your best bet may be: [Burrito 4 Linux](http://code.google.com/p/fb4linux/downloads/detail?name=Burrito4Linux.tar.bz2&can=2&q=) with the [flashpunk](http://flashpunk.net/) libraries for your game engine.
Second most common option is Java, in which case you'd have to use the .applet package for.

Since you have C++ experience, I would recommend trying a flash actionscript compiler. I've personally used FlashBuilder, but I could not run it in Linux, so your next best option is Burrito 4 Linux noted above.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Use the FREE adobe flex SDK on linux.
Gives you flash/flex libraries, and command line tools to compile SWFs, flex, and air applications.